# Think Python [9.2 - Exercise 3] Why are only some of the words forbidden?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code for this exercise:

```
import math

words_file =  open('words.txt')
word = words_file.readline()

def avoids():
forbidden_letters = input('Enter the forbidden letters: ')

for word in words_file:
    for letter in word:
        if letter in forbidden_letters:
            print('Forbidden')
        else:
            print(word)

avoids()
```

Why is my output like this for when I enter the forbidden letters(in this example I entered: aei)?

```
Enter the forbidden letters: aei
Forbidden
Forbidden
aah

aah

Forbidden
Forbidden
aahed
...
```

This is the [words.txt](http://thinkpython2.com/code/words.txt) file.
This is the [Think Python Lesson](http://greenteapress.com/thinkpython2/html/thinkpython2010.html).

Comment: What do you expect the output to be, and why?

Comment: Stepping through your code with a pen and paper should help in this case. We can point our your mistake but that won't be as useful as you finding it yourself.

Comment: @kaya3 I expect it to exclude or print forbidden for the words with any of the letters inputted by the user

Comment: @Selcuk I will give it a try, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of printing out if a letter is forbidden or not for every single individual letter, use a variable to keep track of if you found a forbidden letter, and then only after you're done checking all of the letters, print out if you found one that was forbidden or not.

Spoiler example code. (Click edit to see it formatted properly.)

> for word in words_file:
>         forbidden = False
>
>         for letter in word:
>             if letter in forbidden_letters:
>                 forbidden = True
>                 # Optionally add a break statement here to quit this for loop 
>                 # earlier. We've already found a forbidden letter, so there is 
>                 # no use in checking the rest of them.
>                 break
>
>         # now that you've checked all of the letters, print out the result here
>         if forbidden:
>             print('Forbidden')
>         else:
>             print(word)